# I want to use a neural network for a control block in MATLAB, but without Simulink

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, matlab

I have a physical model that produces an error value after running, which I want to minimize by a Neural Network. I can not find a MATLAB function however that lets me run the program and use the RMSE for training of a network.

How can I use my own model in a loop, combined with a network, so that the error is minimised?